# Getting Environment Variable $PATH in Linux using C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, environment-variables

I am trying to get the value of environment variable $PATH in Linux using a simple C++program as bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    // get PATH using pipe
    FILE* pip = popen("exec bash -c 'echo $PATH'", "r");
    if (!pip)
    {
        printf("can not open pipe!");
        return 1;
    }

    char lineversion[600];
    memset (lineversion, 0, sizeof(lineversion));
    if (!fgets(lineversion, sizeof(lineversion), pip))
    {
        printf("fgets error!");
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << lineversion << std::endl;

    // get PATH using getenv
    char* pPath = getenv ("PATH");
    std::cout << pPath << std::endl;
}
```

I used two different methods: using pipe and using getenv method. They both output this:

> /opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/netbeans-7.3.1/bin

Interestingly the actual value of PATH is something different!

[image]

Why my C++ program is showing a different value for PATH?

Edit 1: I am running my C++ program in Eclipse IDE.

Edit 2: Compiling the program directly (without Eclipse IDE) shows the correct PATH value!

[image]

Edit 3: I found the answer in [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489681/) too.

Comment: What happens when you don't run your program in eclipse?

Comment: Your PATH can be altered by some config file, either for bash, or for NETBEANS. Check your .profile, .bashrc, .bash-profile in your home directory.

Comment: Your PATH is different between eclipse and your shell.

Comment: @Galik: Without Eclipse, it shows the PATH value correctly! I have updated my question. So Eclipse is responsible for this?

Comment: that may be becase, eclipse does not run on bash profile

Comment: Are you using 'Debug' command or 'Run' command. try using 'Run' command see if gets the real PATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process inherits the environment from the process that created it.

This is how Linux works, along with many other operating systems.

If you launch a program from Eclipse, that program inherits Eclipse's environment.
If you launch a program from the shell, that program inherits the shell's environment, including the modifications to `PATH` you have in your init files.

Since Eclipse has inherited *its* environment from whichever process launched it, you should see the expected output if you launch Eclipse from the shell instead of through your desktop GUI.